# How to stop screen from moving up?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am working on a dashboard using the highcharts library, however when I click on the chart the screen moves up. I am using the example code which can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/):

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            },
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
    }]
});
});
```

I've implemented the code in some sort or dashboard where I am working on which can be found here: [dashboard](http://appmazing.nl/artena/index.html).

If you go to the dashboard, scroll a bit down then click on a chart you can see what I mean, the screen shoots up, which is very annoying, especially on mobile devices. The strange thing is, that the examples on the Highcharts website, do not have this behaviour.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your case ordinary link click behavior works. The browser tries to find href, and just adds # into the url and goes up. Try add this to prevent default. `.on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: That was it! I had href on my divs, removed them and it works now. Thanks for your help! Please add it as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case ordinary link click behavior works. The browser tries to find href, and just adds # into the url and goes up. Try add this to prevent default. `.on('click', function() {     event.preventDefault(); });`